# F# - Compare 2 JsonValue'

Tags: json, f#, deserialization

I have 2 Json values that are similar, but there are some differences.

Json1:

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "people" : [
    {
      "Id" : 1421,
      "Name" : "Jackson",
      "Age" : 21,
      "Status" : "Available"
    },
    {
      "Id" : 5916,
      "Name" : "Steven",
      "Age" : 22,
      "Status" : "Available"
    }
  ],
  "totalRecords" : 2
}
```

Json2:

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "people" : [
    {
      "Id" : 1421,
      "Name" : "Jackson",
      "Age" : 21,
      "Status" : "Available"
    },
    {
      "Id" : 5916,
      "Name" : "Steven",
      "Age" : 22,
      "Status" : "Unavailable"
    },
    {
      "Id" : 1337,
      "Name" : "Alice",
      "Age" : 19,
      "Status" : "Available"
    }
  ],
  "totalRecords" : 3
}
```

I'd like to know if there's a way to compare the two Jsonvalues. At the moment I de-serialize the data into a type and then use the Id's and the status' to see if anythings changed. I then pick out the parts that are different (In the example it'd be Steven and Alice) and add them to a sequence for later.

I'd like to reverse a few of the steps. I'd like too compare the json, find the differences, deserialize them and then add them to the sequence, or add them to the sequence then de-serialize the whole sequence. Either way, same result.

Any ideas?

Comment: Seems like a sensible approach to me. What's your problem?

Comment: No problem. Just curious to see if it's possible.

Comment: If _what_ is possible?

Comment: If it's possible to compare the json before I de-serialize.

Comment: Yes, it certainly is. Are you encountering some particular problem when trying to do so?

Comment: No, I just have no clue how to compare json data.

Comment: What do you use to parse it?